# QSettings weird behaviour on MacOS

Tags: c++, macos, qt, qsettings

Using Qt 5.11.1 via homebrew on MacOS 10.13.6, I'm using QSettings in my application. This is a working program that I'm porting from Linux and Windows now to MacOS.

The issue I'm having on MacOS is that it'll save the file to **/Users/michaelleonetti/Library/Preferences/com.sonarcloud.Sonarcloud Service.plist**, which it's supposed to, on first program execution.

If I delete the file *sometimes* it comes back. *Sometimes* it doesn't. If I edit the plist file with Xcode and save it, the values I write in "have" won't be there.

I can't identify a rhyme or a reason to make it work.

I've created a minimal example:

```
#include <QSettings>

#include <iostream>

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{

    { // Scope
        QSettings settings( QSettings::NativeFormat, QSettings::UserScope, "My Application Company", "My Application" );
        if( settings.contains( "have" ) )
            std::cout << "We have: " << settings.value( "have" ).toString().toStdString() << std::endl;
        else
            std::cout << "You do not have" << std::endl;

        settings.setValue( "version", 10 );
        std::cout << "Path is: " << settings.fileName().toStdString() << std::endl;
    }

    return( EXIT_SUCCESS );
}
```

Output:

```
$ ./src/reproduce
You do not have
Path is: /Users/michaelleonetti/Library/Preferences/com.my-application-company.My Application.plist
```

File check

```
$ cat "/Users/michaelleonetti/Library/Preferences/com.my-application-company.My Application.plist"
cat: /Users/michaelleonetti/Library/Preferences/com.my-application-company.My Application.plist: No such file or directory
```

How can I get this issue solved?

Comment: It almost looks as if you were running multiple copies of your process... Could you write a short reproducer?

Comment: @KubaOber added as requested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* this is due to `QSettings` being implemented on top of Apple's `CFPreferences` database. This is expected behavior and the "fix" is to call [CFPreferencesSynchronize()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/1515504-cfpreferencessynchronize?language=objc)

Docs:

> writes all pending changes to preference data to permanent storage,
>   and reads latest preference data from permanent storage

Luckily it appears that QT wraps this in its [Mac implementation](https://github.com/radekp/qt/blob/master/src/corelib/io/qsettings_mac.cpp) for `QSettings` and you should be able to call `QSettings::sync()` to do this in a platform agnostic way.

Basically you need to synchronize your settings before you will see any changes from external writes**. This is also why the file doesn't appear to always be rewritten (it should on application exit when things are automatically flushed).

Note that you will also need synchronize your settings from the external application by calling `CFPreferencesSynchronize()` within that application in order to see changes made by your QT app.

It also might be interesting to know that there is a command line utility available called `defaults` that you can use to perform syncronized writes from a shell script or terminal.

** This occurs naturally at certain points automatically.

Comment: Okay! It now. Thank you. I can just use defaults then to do the same dern thing. Using "defaults write [plist path] have Yes" it works just fine. This more than solves the issue.